# Calculate the angle between two curves $f(x)=x^2$ and $g(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$

Tags: calculus

I want to Calculate the angle between two curves on their intersect $f(x)=x^2$ and $g(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$, what I did so far is:
$$x^2=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} \rightarrow x=1$$then :
$$\tan(a)=\left |\frac{f'(a)-g'(a)}{1+f'(a)*g'(a)}\right| 
$$ after set $x=1$ I get zero at the denominator.

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Do you know which angles the tangent function undefined at? Also, note that the slope of $f(x) = x^2$ at $x=1$ is $2,$ while the slope of $g(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$ at $x=1$ is $-\frac{1}{2},$ and the numbers $2$ and $-\frac{1}{2}$ are negative reciprocals of each other . . .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$(1)\;\;x^2=\frac1{\sqrt x}\implies x=1$$

$$(2)\;f'(1)=2\;,\;f(1)=1\implies\;\text {the tangent line to this function at the intersection point is}$$

$$y-1=2(x-1)\implies y=2x-1$$

$$(3)\;g'(1)=-\frac12\,,\,g(1)=1\implies\;\text {the tangent line to this function at the intersection point is} $$

$$y-1=-\frac12(x-1)\implies y=-\frac12x+\frac32$$

Since the product of the tangent lines' slopes is $\,-1\,$ these lines, and thus the curves...etc.

Comment: So I need to calculate with those equations that angle?

Comment: Ah so its $\frac{\pi}{2}$, Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Also, just note that the slope of $ f(x) $ is $ 2 $ and the slope of $ g(x) $ is $ -\frac{1}{2} $ at $ x = 1 $. Their slopes are perpendicular so the angle is $ \frac{\pi}{2} $. That is why the denominator of your expression is $ 0 $ - $ \tan\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right) $ is similarly undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach that I've found useful in applications (and avoids the "undefined tangent value" problem) is to construct tangent vectors to the two curves, using the formulation $ \  \langle 1 \ ,  \frac{dy}{dx} |_{x = a}  \rangle  $ for each one.

In this problem, we have  $ \ \overrightarrow{T_1} \ = \ \langle 1 , f'(1) \rangle \ = \ \langle 1 , 2 \rangle $ for  $ \ y = x^2 \ $ and $ \ \overrightarrow{T_2} \ = \ \langle 1 , g'(1) \rangle \ = \ \langle 1 , -\frac{1}{2} \rangle \ $ for  $ \ y = \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} \ . $  We find in this problem that

$$ \ \cos \theta \ = \ \frac{\overrightarrow{T_1} \cdot \overrightarrow{T_2} }{|| \overrightarrow{T_1}  || \ || \overrightarrow{T_2}  ||} \ = \ 0 \ , $$

so the curves are orthogonal at $ \ x = 1 \ . $  (This approach works more generally, however.)